# [af]?lex regular expression difference

Tags: bnf, regular-language, flex-lexer, set-difference, alex

I don't know how to do this, and I've found no good resources online for how to perform this operation[.]  I'm trying to take an annotated EBNF production rule which is a difference between two regular expressions and turn it into a(n a| f?)lex grammar specification rule[.]  The problem is that I see no way to do this normally[.]{3} is there a way to do this using Kleene algebra, like the way you can use an empty match with alternation in a context-free grammar[?]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What does the EBNF production rule look like (and can you write that in EBNF?)

The set difference `A\B` between regular expressions is equivalent to intersection with a complement: `A&~B`: the set of strings matched by A, devoid of any strings matched by B. Neither flex nor alex support such semantics in their regular expression languages.

An expression of this form still denotes a regular language, and therefore has an equivalent automaton, for which a regular expression exists based only on the alternation and Kleene operators. This equivalent expression not easy to find, and it depends on the specific internals of A and B. That is to say, we can't just plug A and B into some general regex formula such that the result denotes the set difference.  The original A and B will not appear in the set difference regex.

Comment: I see.  Thanks for the information thus far, it's extremely helpful in understanding why I can't really use the provided grammar for Visual Basic to parse it due to a few rules such as this:

XMLProcessingValue  ::=
< Any XMLString that does not contain the string "?>" >

...unless the written EBNF rule would be:

XMLProcessingValue ::=
XMLString \ "?>"

Is that right? I'm still really new to the mechanics of formal languages.

Comment: EBNF is a formally defined grammar-writing language (look it up on the Wikipedia). It has no operator for set difference. The grammar authors inserted some informal English for what they are not able to express in standard EBNF.

Comment: There is a way to use a regex without the set complement or intersection operators to exclude a digraph like `ab`. Namely something like: `(a*|[^a]*|([^a]*(a[^b]))*)[^b]*`. That is to say, match all strings which are either all `a`, or all non-`a`, or zero or more segments of non-`a` terminated by `a` and a non-`b`, allowing the union of all these possibilities to be trailed by a sequence of zero or more non-`b`'s

Comment: This comes up in the scanning of C language comments, which are `/*` followed by any sequence of characters not containing `*/` followed by `*/`.  One common approach, instead of a tortuous regex, is to handle this via a lex rule which contains custom code to read the input stream and discard the comment, outside of lex's state machine.

Comment: ...huh, awesome, so in order to do set differences, the best way is to implement a secondary lexing state.  That's hopeful.  :/  Thank you, anyway.

Also, I'm aware of EBNF (I had to know it to understand Microsoft's grammar specifications), but since there's no real standard for it, I wasn't sure if anyone included a difference operation in their own interpretation of it and if there were any sort of implementation of said operation.  Thank you for more or less bringing that to my attention.