# Regex help: Identifying websites in text

Tags: regex

I am trying to write a function which removes websites from a piece of text. I have:

```
removeWebsites<- function(text){
  text = gsub("(http://|https://|www.)[[:alnum:]~!#$%&+-=?,:/;._]*",'',text)
  return(text)
}
```

This handles a large set of the problem, but not a popular one, i.e something of the form `xyz.com`

I do not wish to add `.com` at the end of the above regex, as it limits the scope of that regex. However I tried writing some more regexex like:

```
gsub("[[:alnum:]~!#$%&+-=?,:/;._]*.com",'',testset[10])
```

This worked, but it also modified email ids of the form `abc@xyz.com` to `abc@`. I don't want this, so I modified it to

```
gsub("*((^@)[[:alnum:]~!#$%&+-=?,:/;._]*).com",'\\1',testset[10])
```

This left the email ids alone but stopped recognising websites of the form `xyz.com`

I understand that I need some sort of a set difference here, of the form of what was explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9944361/aflex-regular-expression-difference) but I was not able to implement it (mainly because I was not able to completely understand it). Any idea on how I go about solving my problem?

Edit: I tried negative lookaheads:

```
gsub("[[:alnum:]~!#$%&+-=?,:/;._](?!@)[^(?!.*@)]*.com",'',testset[10])
```

I got a 'invalid regex' error. I believe a little help in correcting may get this to work...

Comment: you need `perl=TRUE` for negative lookahead, but it still won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't believe it. There actually is a simple solution to it.

```
gsub(" ([[:alnum:]~!#$%&+-=?,:/;._]+)((.com)|(.net)|(.org)|(.info))",' ',text)
```

This works by:

1. Start with a space.
2. Put all sorts of things, except an '@' in.
3. end with a .com/net/org/info/

Please do look into breaking it! I'm sure there will be cases that will break this as well.

Comment: ccTlds (.de, .at, .ch ...) will break it, a simlpe ... \.info|[a-z]{2}) will do

Comment: Good one. I was looking at catching the popular ones, but this is a great thing to put in!

Answer (score 0):

your lookarounds look a bit funny to me: you cant look behind inside a character class and why are you looking ahead? A look behind is imho more appropriate.
I think the following expression *should* work, although i didn't test it:

```
gsub("*((?<!@)[[:alnum:]~!#$%&+-=?,:/;._]*).com",'\\1',testset[10])
```

also note that lookbehinds must have a fixed length, so no multipliers are allowed

Comment: Error in gsub("*((?<!@)[[:alnum:]~!#$%&+-=?,:/;._]*).com", "\\1", testset[10],  : 
  invalid regular expression '*((?<!@)[[:alnum:]~!#$%&+-=?,:/;._]*).com'
In addition: Warning message:
In gsub("*((?<!@)[[:alnum:]~!#$%&+-=?,:/;._]*).com", "\\1", testset[10],  :
  PCRE pattern compilation error
 'nothing to repeat'
 at '*((?<!@)[[:alnum:]~!#$%&+-=?,:/;._]*).com'